# Java: Try block stops before it's end without any exceptions

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, try-catch

What makes me crazy is that my program stops in the middle of try block and continuous after all catch blocks! Here are details. I got AsyncTask

```
public class BigBitmapLoader extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap>
{

    public BigBitmapLoader(ScribblesView scribbles)
    {
        scribblesRef = new WeakReference<ScribblesView>(scribbles);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... params)
    {
        InputStream is;
        try
        {
            ScribblesView scribs = scribblesRef.get();
            if (scribs != null)
            {
                is = scribs.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(params[0]);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                is.close();
                return bitmap;
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e(ERROR_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(ERROR_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ScribblesView scribs = scribblesRef.get();
        if (scribs != null) scribs.setBigBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private WeakReference<ScribblesView> scribblesRef;

    private static final String ERROR_TAG = "BigBitmapLoader";

}
```

In doInBackground() it comes to `is.close()` and then immediately jumps to `return null` after all catch blocks. Thus it skips `return bitmap`. At this point I got no exceptions. Only later when returned bitmap is used I got NPE. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you indent this code? It's kind of hard to read as is.

Comment: but it is already indented, isn't it?

Comment: My apologies... it was the browser I was using before. Must have not had the right plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I had an exception on main thread. But there was no links on it in log. Here `if (scribs != null) scribs.setBigBitmap(bitmap);` in `setBigBitmap()` I used uninitialized variable. Fixed it and all works. But debuger still "jumps". Maybe some bugs in eclipse's debuger, because now it returns a returns a proper value. And did it before. It was only uninitialized variable.
Thank you all for your answers)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the debugger's line numbers are sometimes off, so maybe that's the issue there. Do a clean build.
Also, I would move is.close() to finally block. It's a good idea in general in order to make sure that you properly dispose the resources. So it would go something like this:

```
InputStream is = null;
try
    {
     // do stuff
} catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    Log.e(ERROR_TAG, e.toString());
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(ERROR_TAG, e.toString());
} finally {
  if (is != null) {
     is.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because of a `NullPointerException` from `is` you just don't see it.  When an exception occurs in an `ExecutorService` from a `Callable` or `Runnable` the exception is swallowed (unless a UncaughtExceptionHandler is set).   **Note** AsyncTask uses (or at least last I checked) the ExecutorService for async execution.

`doInBackground` will run on another thread, if a RuntimeException occurs it will not print anywhere that isn't specified (ie swallow the exception).

I suggest you add a third catch block

```
} catch(RuntimeException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace(); //or log
}
```

In short, the InputStream is probably null.

Answer (score 1):

You see no exceptions because, no exceptions occured

```
        ScribblesView scribs = scribblesRef.get();
        if (scribs != null)
        {
            is = scribs.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
            return bitmap;  // return statement
        }
```

The return statement maybe returns null. try debugging the method "decodeStream"

Comment: I gone through doInBackground in debug mode. Line by line. And it jumps from `is.close()` to return statement after catches. And bitmap isn't null, also checked in while debuging.